# Half cells: difference between E(cell) = E(cathode}-E(anode) & E(cell) = E(oxidation) + E(reduction)

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

When do I use each of the above? If I use one or the other they give me difference results.

For example, I'm trying to put the Volts into an equation to find standard free energy change.

$$\Delta  G^\circ= -nFE$$

If I use the cathode minus anode I get a different answer to the oxide + reduct.

Comment: Hi, could you write out the problem and the calculations that you have done so far so we can get a better context of where you may have made an error?

Answer (score 5):

Ah, I see what you did wrong.

The first equation is correct.

$$ E^\circ_\text{cell} = E^\circ_\text{cathode} - E^\circ_\text{anode} $$

The second equation should be:

$$ E^\circ_\text{cell} = E^\circ_\text{reduction} - E^\circ_\text{oxidation} $$

Alternatively, you can write it as:

$$ E^\circ_\text{cell} = - E^\circ_\text{oxidation} + E^\circ_\text{reduction} $$

The cathode is actually the reduction step, and the anode is the oxidation step.

A useful mnemonic I learned from my chemistry professor is a **red cat** and **an ox.** Interestingly, cathodes in electrochemical cells are red and are positive. So I have found many uses for this along the way.

Answer (score 1):

First, remember the following rules:

| cell type | example | Where does oxidation occur? | Where does reduction occur? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| galvanic cell | battery | minus pole, anode | plus pole, cathode |
| electrolysis cell | water electrolysis | plus pole, anode | minus pole, cathode |

### Gibbs free energy

Let's start with thermodynamics: The change in **Gibbs free energy** $\Delta G$ of a chemical reaction tells you if the reaction can occur without requiring external energy:

- If $\Delta G < 0$, the chemical reaction is **exergonic**, meaning it can run without requiring external energy (it releases energy to the system around it)
- If $\Delta G > 0$, the chemical reaction is **endergonic**, which means it requires external energy to take place.

### Standard Reduction Potential

For electrochemical reactions, every redox pair has its own **standard reduction potential** $E^{\ominus}$. This is always measured as reduction reaction against the standard hydrogen electrode which has a potential of $0\rm\ V$ by definition:

$\rm 2\ H^{+}(aq) + 2 e^- \rightarrow H_2(g) \quad\quad E^{\ominus}_{\rm 2H^{+}//H_2} = 0.0\ V$

$\rm Zn^{2+}(aq) + 2 e^- \rightarrow Zn(s) \quad\quad E^{\ominus}_{\rm Zn^{2+}//Zn} = - 0.76\ V$

$\rm Cu^{2+}(aq) + 2 e^- \rightarrow Cu(s) \quad\quad E^{\ominus}_{\rm Cu^{2+}//Cu} = + 0.34\ V$

Each $E^{\ominus}$ value has a sign. **You must always respect that sign in calculations!** Also note that this value is always associated to the reduction reaction.

The change in Gibbs free energy for a reaction under standard conditions (indicated by $\ominus$, or $0$) is:

$\Delta G^{\ominus} = - zF\Delta E^{\ominus}$

With this you can already understand why some metals are more unreactive than others. Why is copper less reactive than zinc? Let's calculate the change in Gibbs free energy for the reduction reactions of both metal ions to the metal:

$\Delta G^{\ominus}_{\rm Zn^{2+}//Zn} = - 2\cdot 96485 \frac{\rm C}{\rm mol} \cdot (- 0.76\ {\rm V}) \approx +147 \frac{\rm kJ}{\rm mol} > 0\rm\ (endergonic)$

$\Delta G^{\ominus}_{\rm Cu^{2+}//Cu} = - 2\cdot 96485 \frac{\rm C}{\rm mol} \cdot (+ 0.34\ {\rm V}) \approx -65.6 \frac{\rm kJ}{\rm mol} < 0\rm\ (exergonic)$

Note that minus multiplied with minus makes a plus and that coulomb ($\rm A \cdot s$) multiplied with the unit volt $\rm V$ makes energy in the unit joule ($\rm J$).

You now can see that the reduction of copper(II) ions to copper metal in aqueous solution can occur spontaneously, because is it an exergonic reaction, while the reduction of zinc(II) ions to zinc metal cannot, because this reduction is an endergonic reaction.

### What about electrochemical reactions?

Which of the following electrochemical reactions is exergonic?

$\rm Zn(s) + Cu^{2+}(aq) \rightarrow Zn^{2+}(aq) + Cu(s) \rm\ \quad(reaction\ 1)$

$\rm Cu(s) + Zn^{2+}(aq) \rightarrow Cu^{2+}(aq) + Zn(s) \rm\ \quad(reaction\ 2)$

As you stated, the potential difference can be calculated as follows:

$\Delta E^{\ominus} = E^{\ominus}_{\rm reduction} - E^{\ominus}_{\rm oxidation}$

So lets start with the upper reaction. In this case, copper is being reduced and zinc is being oxidized, so:

$\Delta E^{\ominus}_{\rm reaction\ 1} = E^{\ominus}_{\rm reduction} - E^{\ominus}_{\rm oxidation} = E^{\ominus}_{\rm Cu^{2+}//Cu} - E^{\ominus}_{\rm Zn^{2+}//Zn} = + 0.34 {\rm V} - (- 0.76 {\rm V}) = + 1.10 {\rm\ V}$

In reaction 2, zinc gets reduced and copper gets oxidized, so:

$\Delta E^{\ominus}_{\rm reaction\ 2} = E^{\ominus}_{\rm reduction} - E^{\ominus}_{\rm oxidation} = E^{\ominus}_{\rm Zn^{2+}//Zn} - E^{\ominus}_{\rm Cu^{2+}//Cu} =  - 0.76 {\rm V} - (+ 0.34 {\rm V}) = - 1.10 {\rm\ V}$

What does this means for the Gibbs free energy of those reactions?

$\Delta G^{\ominus}_{\rm reaction\ 1} = - 2\cdot 96485 \frac{\rm C}{\rm mol} \cdot (+ 1.10\ {\rm V}) \approx -212 \frac{\rm kJ}{\rm mol} < 0\rm\ (exergonic)$

$\Delta G^{\ominus}_{\rm reaction\ 2} = - 2\cdot 96485 \frac{\rm C}{\rm mol} \cdot (- 1.10 {\rm V}) \approx +212 \frac{\rm kJ}{\rm mol} > 0\rm\ (endergonic)$

From this you can see that reaction 2 is not taking place because it is endergonic, but reaction 1 can take place. This is in agreement with your chemical intuition, because copper is a more noble metal than zinc.

To summarize, I always like to put brackets around the values to make it clear to students that the sign of each value must be respected:

$\Delta E^{\ominus} = (E^{\ominus}_{\rm reduction}) - (E^{\ominus}_{\rm oxidation}) = (E^{\ominus}_{\rm cathode}) - (E^{\ominus}_{\rm anode})$

The half reaction with the more positive $E^{\ominus}$ value will be the reduction, because the reduction reaction for that half reaction is more exergonic.

Answer (score 0):

Some people may use Ecell=Ecathode+Eanode or Ecell=Ereduction+Eoxidation if they keep each redox reaction written in the standard form, i.e. as a reduction, even though the anodic/oxidation reaction is not physically a reduction.

For example, i'f I'm working with a microbial fuel cell oxidizing acetate on the anode over a biocatalyst(E*=-0.29 for CO2 reduction to acetate) and producing water on the cathode over a Pt catalyst (E*=+1.229 for O2 reduction to water), my Ecell is 1.229+(-0.29)=0.939 V.

Answer (score 0):

If the formulae seem daunting, you can just do it intuitively...

Let's consider

$\ce{A+ + B -> A + B+}$

To find the net voltage of the cell, we just add the voltages of the half reactions:

$E_{\text{cell}} = E_{A^+/A} + E_{B/B^+}$

($X^+/X$ can be thought of as $X^+ \rightarrow X$ here)

But we are given the reduction potentials $E_{A^+/A}$ and $E_{B^+/B}$. So just take negative of $E_{B^+/B}$:

$\begin{align}
E_{\text{cell}} &= E_{A^+/A} - E_{B^+/B}\\
&= E_{\text{cat}} - E_{\text{an}}
\end{align}$